# R apply ecdf to every column

Tags: r, apply, ecdf

I am trying to get the ecdf() of each column `c` in a data frame and then feed the rows `r` of a column into that column's `ecdf(c)` to return the corresponding value `ecdf(c)(r)` per cell. The function below works.

```
getecdf <- function(data){
  # initialise result data
  result <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(data), ncol = ncol(data)));
  rownames(result) <- rownames(data); colnames(result) <- colnames(data);
  for (c in 1:ncol(data)){
    col <- data[,c];
    cum <- ecdf(col)
    for (r in 1: length(col)){
      result[r,c] <- cum(col[r])
    }
  }
  return <- result  
}
cum_matrix <- getecdf(iris)
```

However, I am 99.5% sure there is a one liner code that includes `apply` to do this.
I tried:

```
apply(iris, 2, function(x) for (r in x){ ecdf(x)(r)})
```

but don't know how to store the results.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ecdf` is vectorized, you can use

```
apply(iris[, 1:4], 2, function(c) ecdf(c)(c))
```

Comment: `ecdf(c)` returns a (step)function which accepts a vector as argument for evaluation (evaluated at positions `c` again in this example)

Comment: Yes, stupid of me. I have actually fed vectors into `ecdf()` before but for some reason it did not occur to me in this case...